# Problem with combining ForwardDiff and PyPlot in Julia 1.0.5

Tags: function, matplotlib, parameters, julia, array-broadcasting

In Julia 1.0.5, I have a function `f(x::Vector{<:Real})`, defined as

```
f(x::Vector{<:Real}) = (x[1] - 2)^2 + ( x[2] - 1 )^2
```

The signature is like this, because I would like to use it with the `ForwardDiff` package, and it works with it just fine. I give the function to `ForwardDiff.gradient`, and everything works like a charm.

However, I would also like to do some visualizations with `PyPlot`, using this same function `f`. Namely, I would like to draw its contour with `contourf`. For this purpose, I have constructed two vectors `X::Vector{<:Real}` and `Y::Vector{<:Real}`, and would like to call the same function `f` with them to produce the contour.

However, making the call `f.([X, Y])` is not broadcasting the vectors as I would like, as I get the error

```
LoadError: MethodError: no method matching (::getfield(Main, Symbol("#f#1044")))(::Int64)
Closest candidates are:
  f(!Matched::Array{#s25,1} where #s25<:Real)
```

This of course prevents me from using the `contourf` function, as it needs the values of `f` on a 2D-grid.

Do I need to define an entirely different `f(x::Vector{<:Real}, y::Vector{<:Real})` to be able to plot the contour as I would like, or is there an alternative where I can avoid this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this problem can be resolved by the power of multiple dispatch:

```
f(x::Vector{<:Real}) = (x[1] - 2)^2 + ( x[2] - 1 )^2
f(x::Real,y::Real) = f([x,y])
nx = 10
ny = 20
X = rand(nx) #mesh of x points
Y = rand(ny) #mesh of y points
Z = f.(transpose(X),Y) #nx x ny matrix
```

for the two argument gradient:

```
two_point_gradient(f,x,y) = ForwardDiff.gradient(f,[x,y])
G = two_point_gradient.(f,transpose(X),Y) #returns a vector of gradients, where G[i..] = gradient(f,X[i..],Y[i...])
```

Comment: How would this solve the plotting issue? Also, isn't `f(x<:Real)` illegal? Shouldn't it read `f(x::Union{<:Real})`?

Comment: With this, the function value can be calculated with two real arguments. However, the first argument also has to be transposed for the broadcasting to work as intended when using the dotted version of `f(x, y)`, as in`f.(x', y)`.